AWS Amplify default authorization type using API Key
I am learning AWS amplify, and has just deployed my first app using
this tutorial
When I am examining what's been deployed, I found that the when the App is calling the AppSync Query, it's using the hard coded API Key for AppSync. I don't think this is a good solution, because an UserPool has been created in the app, the UserPool instance should be used as the authenticator for AppSync Query, meaning the access token should be sent to the AppSync for data query.
I understand the above configuration was done using with the following codes in the tutorial.
// ./amplify/data/resource.ts
export const data = defineData({
  schema,
  authorizationModes: {
    defaultAuthorizationMode: "apiKey",
    apiKeyAuthorizationMode: {
      expiresInDays: 30,
    },
  },
});

However, I could not find a way to configure "userPool" as the defaultAuthorizationMode and link to the user pool instanced created in the amplify/auth/resource.ts file, with for now has the following codes:
// ./amplify/auth/resource.ts
export const auth = defineAuth({
  loginWith: {
    email: true,
  }
});

There could be the following challenges, to implement what I want:

If AppSync is going to use userPool for authentication, user pool instance needs to be created first, so that it can be passed to AppSync for configuration. So how do I define the dependency in the Amplify backend codes.
How to configure the "defineData" parameters
Does the Ampify front-end has the support for managing and using the tokens. e.g. token storage, token refresh, using token for query. Anyway, how to make the react front end to fit this configuration.

I appreciate if anyone could share the insight. Or if Amplify is no good to support my requirements, any better frameworks?

I used the tutorial for React Native here: https://docs.amplify.aws/react-native/
I combined that with the React Bedrock guide here: https://docs.amplify.aws/react/build-a-backend/data/custom-business-logic/connect-bedrock/
I then configured authorization to allow.authenticated() and I set the defaultAuthorizationMode to userPool.
I am now able to make calls to Bedrock via AppSync with the user logged into the Cognito UserPool.
AppSync is now configured with primary auth mode set to AMAZON_COGNITO_USER_POOLS.
Here are the full contents of amplify/data/resource.ts, which works in my case:
import { type ClientSchema, a, defineData } from "@aws-amplify/backend";

const schema = a.schema({
  generateHaiku: a
    .query()
    .arguments({ prompt: a.string().required() })
    .returns(a.string())
    .authorization((allow) => [allow.authenticated()])
    .handler(
      a.handler.custom({
        dataSource: "BedrockDataSource",
        entry: "./generateHaiku.js",
      })
    ),
});

export type Schema = ClientSchema<typeof schema>;

export const data = defineData({
  schema,
  authorizationModes: {
    defaultAuthorizationMode: "userPool",
    apiKeyAuthorizationMode: {
      expiresInDays: 30,
    },
  },
});

